# How to pass a string variable to a PowerShell function from python

Tags: python, string, function, powershell, variables

How can I pass variable colors to be printed from a python script by calling a powershell function.

```
function check($color){
    Write-Host "I have a $color shirt"
}
```

```
import subprocess
color = "blue"
subprocess.call(["powershell.exe", '-Command', '&{. "./colortest.ps1"; & check(color)}'])
```

Above code results in below error

```
color : The term 'color' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:27
+ &{. "./colortest.ps1"; & check(color)}
+                           ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (color:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If I directly insert the actual color as a constant parameter, then I get the desired result but replacing it with a variable fails.

```
subprocess.call(["powershell.exe", '-Command', '&{. "./colortest.ps1"; & check("blue")}'])
```

Result

```
I have a blue shirt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) the code could be as follows. Note, when calling the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-command) with the `-Command` parameter, there is no need to use `& {...}`, PowerShell will interpret the string as the command you want to execute. There is also no need for [`&` (call operator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-) when calling your function (`check`) and lastly, function parameters in PowerShell are either [named (`-Color`) or positional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#parameter-position), don't use `(...)` to wrap your parameters.

```
import subprocess
color = "blue"
subprocess.call([ 'powershell.exe', '-c', '. ./colortest.ps1; check -color {0}'.format(color) ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here at this part:

```py
'&{. "./colortest.ps1"; & check(color)}'
```

is that you're passing the string `color` to the function `check`. you need to pass the value of the local variable `color` instead. so you can use [F-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

```py
subprocess.call(["powershell.exe", '-Command', f"&{. "./colortest.ps1"; & check({color})}"])
```